# Chrome/Safari: jQuery works in .htm but not in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, jquery, safari, dialog, webkit

I have a site where I display some jQuery dialogs. But in Chrome/Safari the dialog is not opened in center of the screen but a long way down the page. The site is programmed in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) but when I copy-paste the generated HTML to a .htm file the thing works fine. Very weird :/

Try:
http://tinyurl.com/yj4vkm7  - works in Safari/Chrome.

And:
http://tinyurl.com/yj32kz9 - do not work in Safari/Chrome.

Click on the "Tilmeld hold!" buttons below Google Maps images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference I found was this at the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The resolution most likely requires removing that.

Comment: I was serving the page as application/xhtml+xml to safari/chrome and that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Each page displays the same in Firefox 3.5.

Do you have a diff tool?  I used one on the output of your two pages.  ChaosPandion noted the first diff, which is at the top of aspx page.

A diff tool will help you find differences between two files.  There are other differences I easily found, like at lines 40 and 41 (41 and 42 in the aspx file) for instance.

```
open: function(event, ui) { $('object.frame').hide(); },
close: function(event, ui) { $('object.frame').show(); }
```

vs

```
open: function(event, ui) { $('object.legacy').hide(); },
close: function(event, ui) { $('object.legacy').show(); }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: frame vs. legacy is not the fault. I'll check <?xml>. Do you know a diff tool which compare the html? I have SuperPreview from MS, but it is graphical.